# C# How to add List of string to a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a `list of string` to a `list`. Following is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> customBindingRow = new List<string>();
            List<List<string>> customBindingData = new List<List<string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                customBindingRow.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    customBindingRow.Add("i=" + i.ToString() + "j=" + j.ToString());
                }

                customBindingData.Add(customBindingRow);
            }

            string text = "";
            foreach (List<string> dt in customBindingData)
            {
                text += string.Join(",", dt.ToArray()) + "\r\n";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

But when I `Console.WriteLine` it is showing only the last added `list`.

**Here is the output**

```
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
```

**Expected output**

```
i=0j=0,i=0j=1
i=1j=0,i=1j=1
i=2j=0,i=2j=1
i=3j=0,i=3j=1
i=4j=0,i=4j=1
i=5j=0,i=5j=1
i=6j=0,i=6j=1
i=7j=0,i=7j=1
i=8j=0,i=8j=1
i=9j=0,i=9j=1
```

Comment: `customBindingRow.Clear()` is removing all items from the `customBindingRow` list...

Comment: You are adding the *same* list 10 times

Comment: Basically, you've only ever got a single `List<string>` object - but you're adding references to that list multiple times.

Comment: erm, `customBindingData.Add(customBindingRow);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `customBindingRow` is the same object used for the loop 10 times. You just clear it's content for each loop.

You must reinitialize your `customBindingRow`, not by `Clear` it.

```
var customBindingData = new List<List<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var customBindingRow = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        customBindingRow.Add("i=" + i.ToString() + "j=" + j.ToString());
    }

    customBindingData.Add(customBindingRow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You add same object, created in

```
List<string> customBindingRow = new List<string>();
```

10 times, and 10 times modify the object, by clearing and adding new strings.

Just replace clearing with creation of new object to be inserted to collection.

```
customBindingRow.Clear();
```

=>

```
customBindingRow = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost near to your expected answer. Do not initialize customBindingRow, just create it and replace your `customBindingRow.Clear()` line with `customBindingRow = new List<string>;` because .Clear() removes all items from the list.

```
 List<string> customBindingRow;
 List<List<string>> customBindingData = new List<List<string>>();

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      customBindingRow = new List<string>();
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      {
           customBindingRow.Add("i=" + i.ToString() + "j=" + j.ToString());
      }

      customBindingData.Add(customBindingRow);
  }
  string text = "";
  foreach (List<string> dt in customBindingData)
  {
      text += string.Join(",", dt.ToArray()) + "\r\n";
  }

  Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't know the reason, why someone down vote my answer ? Is there anything wrong in it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your exemple, you modify your `customBindingRow` and at the end your `customBindingData` has ten times the same list.

And finally, aditionning strings is not an efficent way. Use `StringBuilder` class instead.

Instead you can try like this :

```
List<string> customBindingRow;
List<List<string>> customBindingData = new List<List<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    customBindingRow = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        customBindingRow.Add("i=" + i.ToString() + "j=" + j.ToString());
    }

    customBindingData.Add(customBindingRow);
}

//Using stringbuilser will reduce the memory usage.
//Adding text to a string will create a new reference in memory, you should avoid this.
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

foreach (List<string> dt in customBindingData)
{
    text.Append( string.Join(",", dt.ToArray()) + "\r\n");
}

Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
```